# Generate upload url before form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am trying to resolve expired upload urls by delaying their generation before a file uploads and not when the form is rendered. A solution I found is to do this on form submission or on button click events like so:

```
$('#btn-upload').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var uploadUrl = '';
  $.get( "/generate_upload_url", function(data) {
    uploadUrl = data;
  });

  $('#my-form').attr('action', uploadUrl);
});
```

And on the serverside I have a Handler that generates upload urls like so:

```
class GenerateUploadUrlHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write(upload_url)
```

I would expect when I click the button to generate new upload url and make a POST request there, but what happens is the form's action is filled with a delay and the POST request is done to a wrong URL. I suspect this might be because I'm doing async GET request and my form is submitted at the same time, but I'm not exactly sure as I see similar examples here: 
http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-part-3-Multiple-upload-support

Comment: I see you are using `event.preventDefault();` it shall prevent your form from being submitted when clicking the submit button. Are you sure the click event is being invoked?

Comment: Yes, the `preventDefault()` was needed because I am submitting the form through a file upload interface elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try:

1) put your `$('#my-form').attr('action', uploadUrl);` inside the `$.get()`' success callback above.

2) if that doesn't work, switch from `$.get()` to `$.ajax()`, and set `async` to false.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really like setting async to false when using ajax. It can kill your page completely if the server is not responding.

You can try bind your event handler with the form submit event instead of the button click event. and set the action attribute of the form in the success event of the ajax call, then trigger the submit event of the form

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var uploadUrl = '';
  $.get( "/generate_upload_url", function(data) {
    uploadUrl = data;
    $('#my-form').attr('action', uploadUrl);
    $('#my-form').trigger("submit");
  });


});
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by changing the `$.get()` to `$.ajax({async:false})`, so I guess I was not supposed to do it through async request.

Comment: This is not a realistic solution.  You really should __never__ use synchronous ajax requests outside of web workers.  Doing so can easily lock up the UI thread for a noticeable amount of time.  Take a look at some of the other solutions offered here.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. I answered my question too fast and didn't see the other answers.